# C# - Iterate through given type elements inside a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, types

I've got an abstract class (Object2D), and several class that inherits Object2D (DisplayObject2D for instance)

I use a List to store all references to these objects.

I'd like to iterate through every DisplayObject2D in this List.

So far, the following code is working, but being new to C# development, I wanted to know if there wasn't any better practice to do so :

```
List<Object2D> tmp = objects.FindAll( delegate( Object2D obj )
                                      { return obj is DisplayObject2D; } );
foreach( DisplayObject2D obj in tmp )
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ZedK : +1 Good question : ties in with something I'm working on right now. I'm pretty sure you realize you can use George's answer directly in the foreach loop, but I'll mention it, just in case : foreach(Object2D obj in objects.OfType<DisplayObject2D>()) { ... } : of course you may have other reasons for preserving the filtered objects in 'tmp, so you may not want to "fire and forget" the result of the filtering by Type.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just done (after adding the missing "using System.Linq" statement), everything is done in just one line, it's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var objects2d = objects.OfType<DisplayObject2D>();
```

if you want an IEnumerable

```
var listOfObjects2d = objects2d.ToList();
```

if you want a List

Note that OfType will give you a more specific type

```
IEnumerable<DisplayObject2D>
```

If it's not what you expected, use Cast extension to cast it back to an enumerable of base type.

```
var listOfObjects2dFilteredByMoreSpecificType = 
 objects.OfType<DisplayObject2D>.Cast<Object2D>()
//.ToList() // until you really need an IList<T> better leave it just an enumerable
;
```

Comment: @George +1, thanks; your answer cleared up a spot of trouble I was in using 'OfType ... I was omitting the empty parens at the end.

Comment: Actually, "objects" is a List<Object2D>, and it seems that this OfType method doesn't exist (it doesn't appear in the autocompletion window) =/
I've been looking for "OfType" in MSDN, but I didn't really understood how to use it.

Comment: To use it, you have to declare using System.Linq namespace and a reference to System.Core dll.

Comment: Now it works just fine, and it's really easy to use ! Thanks a lot for your help ! =)